# Selenium Python extract text between Span

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to extract the text "Margaret Osbon" from HTML below via Python with Selenium. But I keep getting blank values when I print. I have tried get_attribute
Still getting blank values when I print

```
<div class="author-info hidden-md">
                By (author)&nbsp;

                    <span itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope="Margareta Osborn">
                        <a href="/author/Margareta-Osborn" itemprop="url">
                            <span itemprop="name">
                                Margareta Osborn</span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

Below is my code for Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time"

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.bookdepository.com/")

keyword = "9781925324402"

Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="book-search-form"]/div[1]/input[1]'))
        )
Search.clear()
Search.send_keys(keyword)
Search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    authors = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='author-info hidden-md']/span/a/span").text
    print(authors)
    driver.quit()

except:
    authors = "Not Available"
    print(authors)
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `.text` method which is present in the Selenium Python binding.

`.text` is present for `web element`

```
authors = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='author-info hidden-md']/span/a/span").text
print(authors)
```

or

```
authors = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/author/Margareta-Osborn')]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(authors)
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.bookdepository.com/Rose-River-Margareta-Osborn/9781925324402")
authors = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.author-info.hidden-md span[itemprop='author'] span"))).text
print(authors)
```

Comment: I tried that cruise, but its still showing as blank

Comment: Is URL public ? Can you try the second solution ?

Comment: i tried the 2nd solution and still not giving me the text. This is the URL - https://www.bookdepository.com/Rose-River-Margareta-Osborn/9781925324402

Comment: ` Margareta Osborn` this is present 5 times in UI. which one you want to extract ?

Comment: thanks cruise for getting back so soon. I am looking to extract the one under span itemprop="author"

Comment: that did it. thanks heaps. So just have to add more wait time? and search for elements via CSS instead of XPATH?

Comment: I think CSS or XPATH both are okay, yes you should introduce wait for more reliability. CSS have been more consistence as compare with XPATH

Comment: does the maximize_window() matter?

Comment: Would you mind accepting this answer and upvoting if it helped you?

Comment: does the maximize_window() matter - yes that's define the Selenium view port.. always launch in full screen so that selenium will have a better view port.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ".text" to get the value and maybe because of that you are getting some junk value. I am thinking that you are receiving just a reference ID for that.

**Using .text -**

```
#Get Element using Xpath
element = //span[@itemprop='name']

#Fetch using the driver findElement
author = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element).text

#Print the text
print(author)
```

**Using JavaScriptExecutor -**

```
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerText;', element)
```

**Using Get Attribute -**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(element).get_attribute('innerText')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from span. Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `visibility_of_element_located()` and following `css selector`.

and use either `.text` or `.get_attribute("textContent"))`

```
driver.get('https://www.bookdepository.com/Rose-River-Margareta-Osborn/9781925324402')
print(WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.author-info.hidden-md [ itemprop="author"]'))).text)
print(WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.author-info.hidden-md [ itemprop="author"]'))).get_attribute("textContent"))
```

you need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```